# Альтернатива ZoneEdit. Как?

Tags: веб-программирование, сеть, dns, хостинг

Всем привет!

Ребята, такая проблема: зареган у меня домен у каличного регистратора, меняет он только по хитрой инструкции и в течение 3 рабочих дней, и, когда он сменит (утром/вечером), не известно, но мне нужно точно... Сайт может "лежать" максимум 30 мин.

Слышал, что можно с помощью ZoneEdit как-то сделать, чтобы можно было редактировать настройки домена без обращения к доменному регистратору. ZoneEdit - уже платный, подскажите нормальный сервис бемплатный, всего для одного сайта.

Правильно ли я понимаю, у доменного мне нужно прописать параметры ZoneEdit, а уже в ZoneEdit я ставлю параметры, какие мне нужны, таким образом исключаю общения с своим доменным.

**Обновление**

Мне нужно менять параметр ns сервера на домене, но у моего доменного регистратора нет для клиента (меня) панели. Они сами меняют по письму в течение 4 рабочих дней, и не известно, когда именно. Поэтому я сам хочу управлять доменом, и, как мне сказали, могут помочь сервисы вроде zoneedit.

Comment: Что конкретно требуется?

Comment: @Lifeact, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Ок. Вопрос решаемый и бесплатный (делегирование домена): [яндекс-домен](https://pdd.yandex.ru/domain). Зарегистрируйся и сделай Яндекс основным DNS-сервером для твоего домена. Обновление записей в течение 10-30 мин.

Comment: Спасибо, это: Шаг 2. Настроить MX-записи

Я так понимаю, должен мой текущий регистратор домена прописать в настройках моего домена? И вот тут http://take.ms/ShopL, я так понимаю, я могу сразу прописать нс сервера моего текущего хостера, чтобы простоя сайта практически не было? То есть доменный регистратор меняет настройку на яндекс, а на яндексе уже прописаны нс хостера, и все работает. Уточню: у меня хостер один, а доменный регистратор другой.

Comment: Не забудьте отметить, что ответ принят :)
Я так понимаю сменился ip: пропиши новый и все. Зачем менять имя. Ничего менять не надо доменному регистратору, хостер пусть заменит - но это не срочно.
Почту у яндекса заводить необязательно. Но можешь и там прописать MX-записи сам.
Запиши самое главное:@ A XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, а @ NS dns1.yandex.net. оставь - тогда DNS-ом будет яндекс.

Comment: Не забуду, но мои догадки в комменте выше вашего верны? =)

Comment: А зачем? Не устраивала же скорость выполнения работ хостером - я прав? Поэтому и обратились к яндексу. Я у себя на хостинге прописал и яндексовские DNS сервера, и хостера, только яндексовские первыми. Поэтому если мне придется менять ip (а уже приходилось) или имя, то я его сменю на яндекс-DNS, который работает в разы быстрее.